# How to assign to member variables of a class from a member function

Tags: f#

Very new to F#. I have a class like this

```
namespace FsharpTestSystem

open System
open System.IO
open System.Text
open System.Diagnostics

open System.CodeDom
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SourceCodeServices
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.Interactive.Shell
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.SimpleSourceCodeServices

type TestSystem() =
// Intialize output and input streams
// Build command line arguments & start FSI session

    let argv = [| "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\F#\\4.1\\Framework\\v4.0\\fsi.exe" |]
    let allArgs = Array.append argv [|"--noninteractive"|]

    let sbOut = new StringBuilder()
    let sbErr = new StringBuilder()
    let inStream = new StringReader("")
    let outStream = new StringWriter(sbOut)
    let errStream = new StringWriter(sbErr)
    let fsiConfig = FsiEvaluationSession.GetDefaultConfiguration() 


....
```

I add a member method (function) to this class. But how do I assign the return value to a member variable of the class so that can be seen by the rest of the members? In other words, `fsis` needs to be used by other members of `TestSystem`

In C# this is trivial for example through the use of properties. I suspect that I need to tell the F# system that `fsis` is mutable somehow when declaring it.

```
member this.LoadFSI() =
    fsis = FsiEvaluationSession.Create(fsiConfig, allArgs, inStream, outStream, errStream)

member this.UseFSI() =
     //I need to use fsis in here.
```

Comment: For example how will fsiConfig, etc. be available inside your class? Would it be possible to post something simple in C# that does what you want?

Comment: I modified the F# example. Those variables are irrelevant except to initialize this function FsiEvaluationSession.Create. After that they are not used.

Comment: BTW, the reason that I cannot do the FsiEvaluationSession.Create in the constructor is that the program crashes if I put it there. If I put it in a member function, it works. However, I can't access the return value from anywhere else.

Comment: I see. Something like this maybe? `type TestSystem2()  =
    member val X  = 0. with get, set
    member __.MkRand() = __.X <- rand.NextDouble()
    member __.Z = __.X`

Comment: fsis is of type FsiEvaluationSession not int. Is there a null in F#?

Comment: How do I say in the constructor. "fsis is of type FsiEvaluationSession and it will be initialized later"

Comment: yes, there is null. You can just specify a type annotation: `member val X:FsiEvaluationSession = FsiEvalutionSession() with get, set`, it feels a bit convoluted, so maybe you'll get a better answer from someone who uses classes extensively.  However I'm not familiar with this type, it seems it's in the compiler services namespace. Can you also add all the namespaces you are opening?

Answer (score 0):

You do live on the cutting edge... How about this:

```
type TestSystem()  =
    // ....
    [<DefaultValue>] val mutable Fsis : FsiEvaluationSession
    member __.LoadFsis() = __.Fsis <- FsiEvaluationSession.Create(fsiConfig, allArgs, inStream, outStream, errStream)
    member __.UseFsis() = __.Fsis.GetHashCode()


let ts = TestSystem()
ts.LoadFsis()
ts.UseFsis()
ts.Fsis.GetHashCode()
ts.LoadFsis()
ts.UseFsis()
```

From the hashcode (I assume) you can see that as long as you do not do `.LoadFsis` it is using the same session. I'm sure this can be made prettier.